# document and window height return the same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, height, document

For some reason both document height and window height return the same value, so when subtracting window from document height it returns 0. Anyone know why this might be happening?

```
console.log($(window).height());

console.log($(document).height());
```

The above both return the document height

Comment: possibly because they are the same? you'll need to add some more information about your issue..

Answer (score 11):

You might have forgotten the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the page.

Comment: This fixed it for me, after I deleted the space between `!` and `DOCTYPE`. You may want to update your answer. Thanks!

Comment: this is amazing , i thought `<!DOCTYPE html>` is useless

Answer (score 5):

That's because your document fills the viewport (the zone accessible for displaying the document).

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/) :

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

If you document is long enough to take more than one page, the second value may be greater than the first (at least if the document is inside an iframe, look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJ2EB/1/)). There can be other cases generating differences but I have none in mind now.

Comment: It is possible for the `document` to be smaller than the `window` though.

Comment: it could also be a problem with doctype or other problems when your page is longer than the viewport

Comment: @bia.migueis You don't need to look for the doctype. It's normal for the document to be bigger than the window.

Comment: the question doesnt specify that the content is longer than the window so you shouldnt assume it.

Comment: I don't assume it. See *"if"*.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issues that I was able to fix.
I found that

```
$(window).height();
```

Was returning the entire height of the page in FF.
Eventually I realized that I was outputting a debug phrase 'test' before any of the html of the page. IE before the Doc type.

Once this 'test' text was removed the view port height was return as expected.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just couldn't understand what was the issue, finally figured it out thanks to you. in my case it my a var_dump before the doctype

Comment: The highest voted answer to this question isn't a solution because for me it was just as the poster stated, the doc height and the window height were the same and obviously larger than the window really was. I then made sure I had declared the DOCTYPE and I had. I noticed that someone had put a meta tag at the beginning before the DOCTYPE declaration. I removed it and that fixed it for me. This is a FF bug. Nothing can come before the DOCTYPE or it will report the window height to be as long as the document height.